# Can I hide certain comments from comment-based help in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, comments

I'm currently writing a PowerShell script to audit and take action on stale computer objects in our AD structure. Trying to be a good scripter, I'm implementing comment-based help. It's working, but I'm trying to use the syntax where you comment your params and they automatically show up under the `.PARAMETERS` section of the help.

I don't want to use a separate `.PARAMETERS` section in the proper comment-based help comment code if I can avoid it, so that the comments stay with the params, physically. But if there's no way to avoid my issue, then I guess I'll have to.

The problem is that a few of my params use validation, and I've commented bits of the validation code. However, the comment-based help includes all of these misc. comments and I'd rather it didn't as it clutters up the get-help output and doesn't add any value there.

Here's an extract of the code:

```
function audit-StaleADComputersInOU {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Exports a list of AD Computer objects to the screen, and optionally to a CSV formatted file.
Optionally take other actions on returned objects.
Results are from one or more given OU DNs, and filtered by LastLogonTimeStamp.

.OTHER COMMENT-BASED HELP SECTIONS
etc. etc., not including .PARAMETERS
#>


    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]

    param(
        # Specify the full filepath to a file.
        # Results will be exported in CSV format to that file.
        # Parent directory must exist.
        # Omit to export nothing and create no file.
        [ValidateScript({
            # Parent directory
            $path = Split-Path -Path $_

            # Check parent directory exists
            if(!(Test-Path $path)) {
                throw "$path directory doesn't exist!"
            }
            # Check parent directory is actually a directory
            if(!(Test-Path $path -PathType Container)) {
                throw "$path is not a directory!"
            }
            # Check file doesn't already exist
            if(Test-Path $_){
                throw "$_ already exists!"
            }
            return $true
        })]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]
        $ExportToCSV,

        # Other params, etc.
    )

    # Doing stuff
}
```

And here's the relevant output for `Get-Help audit-StaleADComputersInOU -full`:

```
NAME
    audit-StaleADComputersInOU

SYNOPSIS
    Exports a list of AD Computer objects to the screen, and optionally to a CSV formatted file.
    Optionally take other actions on returned objects.
    Results are from one or more given OU DNs, and filtered by LastLogonTimeStamp.


.OTHER COMMENT-BASED HELP SECTIONS
    etc. etc., not including .PARAMETERS


PARAMETERS
    -ExportToCSV <FileInfo>
        Specify the full filepath to a file.
        Results will be exported in CSV format to that file.
        Parent directory must exist.
        Omit to export nothing and create no file.
        Parent directory
        Check parent directory exists
        Check parent directory is actually a directory
        Check file doesn't already exist

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    3
        Default value
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false

    -OtherParams [<SwitchParameter>]
        etc.
```

Is there any way to avoid this? Any comment syntax I can use to make specific comments invisible to comment-based help? Or is my only option to extract the comments I want visible into a `.PARAMETERS` section of the comment-based help syntax at the top of the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comments above the parameter attributes and within are being interpreted as parameter comments because you use other comment based help sections but not `.PARAMETER` for that parameter. What `Get-Help` does in this situation is assume that the comments above the parameters should be the description.

To stop this from happening, you must have a `.PARAMETER <param name>` in your main comment based help for each parameter. There is no other way other than removing the comments from the parameter. You do not need a description for the parameter, although I recommend adding one.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Exports a list of AD Computer objects to the screen, and optionally to a CSV formatted file.
Optionally take other actions on returned objects.
Results are from one or more given OU DNs, and filtered by LastLogonTimeStamp.

.OTHER COMMENT-BASED HELP SECTIONS
etc. etc., not including .PARAMETERS

.PARAMETER ExportToCSV
#>
```

The above will ensure comments on the parameters will not be included in help. If you want a description, put it underneath just like any other comment based help section.

Reference: https://www.sapien.com/blog/2015/02/18/troubleshooting-comment-based-help/

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks.